# How To Minimize Initial Plugin Load Time In Dynamics 365 (CRM)

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

At my current client we have a custom landing page for Phone Pop from the telephony system.  The page performs a search in CRM Online for the client, and then creates a new lead if not found.  On initial calls for the day, the creation of the new lead is extremely long, taking 20-30 seconds.  After 5 or so requests, this drops down to about 3 seconds:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is entirely plugin related because the 3 requests listed in the chart that were always sub second, were standard OData rest queries.  The other 3 requests trigger plugins.

Anyone have any good suggestions/workarounds for keeping these plugins cached?

Comment: 1) What is the size of the plugin DLL? What code exists in the plugin that would execute on creation of the object but not on subsequent calls to the `Execute` method?

Comment: The Plugin dll itself is around 8 MB, which I'm thinking isn't helping anything when it comes to loading the plugin.  The code that is getting executed is the exact same code that is getting executed on other requests

Answer (score -1):

Well as much as I know there isn't anything much you can do about it.

The only way I could recommend you is to isolate target code in a separate dll and create a separate assembly ,after that create a workflow that triggers these plugins,just make sure that the code doesn't really do anything since we just need to keep it alive.